# Mysql Converting date to days of week

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, weekday

I have the following query which gives me the  `visit_date` for each client:

```
select visit_date from visit
```

The output of the  above query is the timestamp when the entry was inserted into the Database , it  will appear as follows :

```
visit_date
2013-12-21 06:31:04
2013-12-21 11:05:30
2013-12-21 23:03:12
```

How can I convert the above date to days of the week in MySQL?

Comment: Just to clarify the query gives you more than one date per person, or is this for three different users?

Answer (score 5):

Check [**MySQL DATETIME FUNCTIONS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) to fetch **day of week** or **day name** or **day of month** or **day of year**

Try this:

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(visit_date) FROM visit;
SELECT DAYNAME(visit_date) FROM visit;
SELECT DAYOFMONTH(visit_date) FROM visit;
SELECT DAYOFYEAR(visit_date) FROM visit;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(visit_date) FROM visit
```

it returns the weekday index for date (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, ..., 7 = Saturday)

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the date with plain php.

```
date_format($visit_date, 'formatstring');
```

l (lowercase 'L')
A full textual representation of the day of the week
Sunday through Saturday

[phpdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Watch out with locale stored on the server of course if your site should be multilang.